Cors Error when calling microservice from Vue frontend application
I have a problem with a call from vue to a spring boot microservice.
Locally it works, while in the test environment where the call is intercepted by KrakenD I have a CORS error
This is my configuration class:

This is the error screen I get:

I tried to change the properties of the WebConfig class by setting allowedOrigins([myLocalHost], [testEnvironmentUrl]), but I ended up with the same results

Did you check if krakend removes the origin headers?

If you are testing it locally, is krakend running also on localhost?  And is the CORS module enabled? https://www.krakend.io/docs/service-settings/cors/

In local I am not using KrakenD and the CORS module is disabled. The KrakenD is setted to accept any request for now and so it shouldn't remove the headers

I don't know much about Krakend but the module description sounds like it is necessary in case of cross-origin requests. Otherwise you will run into the blocked requests problem. Maybe you should enable this module and try again. For instance, you will need this configuration if your web page is hosted at https://www.example.com and the Javascript references the KrakenD API at https://api.example.com.

Finally found the problem. KrakenD had set Same_Origin instead of Cross_Origin

i solved this problem by changing WebConfig like this:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        }
    };
}

}


Thanks in advance for the help. I cannot use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() since it is deprecated and I already tried adding allowCredentials(true) but it doesn't work

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated but it works perfectly, i used WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  because the same example like yours did not work for me

I Understand, however I cannot use anything that is deprecated
